# i need to setup my domain with nginx server for node.js project

Tags: node.js, nginx, subdomain, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04

i have already added CNAME & A Record in my server also i check with nginx command:

```
nginx -t

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

i write code for my domain example.co & www.example.co: /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.co www.example.co;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.co$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ;

    server_name example.co www.example.co;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example-co.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:1000";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem;
}
```

IP: 127.0.0.1:1000 node.js project for example.co
my issue is example.co is working fine but www.example.co is not working

also i have write code for my domain sub1.example.co & www.sub1.example.co: /etc/nginx/sites-available/sub1-example.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub1.example.co www.sub1.example.co;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.co$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ;

    server_name sub1.example.co www.sub1.example.co;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/sub1-example-co.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:2000";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

IP: 127.0.0.1:2000 node.js project for sub1.example.co,

my sub1.example.co is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `www.example.co` to your server block with `443`:

```
server {
    .....
     server_name example.co www.example.co;
    .....
}
```

For your subdomain,  suggest to use another file for your server blocks configuration using the same format: one server block for 80 and another for 443. :)

Comment: i add this but not working www.example.co is show me error "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: In that case, you've probably missed adding a CNAME record in your DNS configuration where you mapped your A record to your server IP address. Please confirm you added this record and try again. Thanks!

Comment: i have already added CNAME  for www and A record for my ip and domain

Comment: My original answer still stands. Your edited server block with 443 shows `sub1.example.co`. You need to add `www.example.co` beside `example.co` . Otherwise, www.example.co will definitely be unreachable. For `sub1.example.co`, please use another file beside the `default`file  in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and don't forget to enable the new site configuration.

Comment: i have also change server_name example.co www.example.co & also i have create new conf file for sub1.example.co but it's not working

Comment: Did you check your config by running `nginx -T` then reloading Nginx by running `nginx -s reload`? (assuming no errors)

Comment: Please check my updated question.. 
i also check this output is: 
`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful ` @johnsing